# Código Pinescript error de tipo de dato

Tags: pine-script

Quiero hacer un indicador en pinescript que vaya calculando vela a vela el percentil 95 de las últimas 100 velas, de la distancia entre el close y las sma(25). Y me da este error continuamente que no sé cómo solucionar:

> Error en 16:34 Could not find function or function reference 'array.to_series'

El código es el siguiente:

```
//@version=5
strategy('Percentil_Distancias',overlay=false)
// Media móvil de 25
ma = ta.sma(close, 25)

// Distancia del close a la media móvil
distance = math.abs(close - ma)

// Percentil 95 y 5 de la distancia de las últimas 100 velas
distance100 = array.new_float(0)

for i = 0 to 99
    array.push(distance100, distance[i+1])

p95=ta.percentile_nearest_rank(source=distance100,length=100,percentage=95)

// Plot de la distancia, percentil 95 y 5
plot(distance, color=color.blue, title="Distancia")
plot(p95, color=color.red, title="Percentil 95")
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: que es "ta.percentile_nearest_rank"? ¿Estás usando chatGPT?.
Debido a tan poca precisión Stackoverflow ha [prohibido ChatGPT](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido).  
TradingView también ha decidido [no proporcionar ningún soporte de control de calidad para ChatGPT](https://es.tradingview.com/chart/TRAIA/gb9r2chz/).

Comment: Sí, es cierto. No vale para codificar porque se inventa funciones y métodos.